# In need of help - eclipse - import image

Tags: eclipse, image, import

Hello i've just started today, so i am very new at this.

I'm following this toturial and i ran into a trouble when i was asked to import a picture as the background for this "game".

i've created a new source folder and placed the picture there

```
    package com.scrollshooter.www;

    public class Board {
    Pig p;
    Image img;

public board(){

}
    }
```

Looks like this at the moment, and the person who created this toturial says that i have to import the picture and afterwards he hover the "image" and there he has the picture. i have no idea how to import the picture into the file

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

make a new folder into your project name it "img", put the image in the folder .
import image using the path like : img/test.png

Comment: Okay i've created the folder and added the picture to the folder. the image is called "skyer.jpg" 

Could you please give me an exampel ?

Comment: image = ImageIO.read(new File("image name and path"));
if you are using eclipse it is going to import all needed packages .